# Cannot upgrade SharePoint Foundation 2010 content database after applying SP1

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Simple two-server farm:
One SharePoint Foundation 2010 WFE on Windows Server 2008 R2 Std SP1
One SQL Server 2008 Std SP1 backend on Windows Server 2008 SP2

I've just installed Service Pack 1 (14.0.6029.1000) on the SharePoint server and rebooted. Central Administration shows that content databases need upgrading:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase Current Schema Version: 14.0.4762.1000, Maximum Schema Version: 14.0.6029.1000

I expected the service pack installation would have done this. I've tried upgrading the databases with the **Upgrade-SPContentDatbase** powershell cmdlet but receive the message:

> WARNING: Database [SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content] cannot be upgraded.

What's wrong? Apologies if the answer is obvious to someone else. This is my first SharePoint deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newbie error as I feared...

I didn't realise I needed to run the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard again after installation and reboot. This fixed it right away.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying any of this, take a local backup of your content DB (WSS_Content)

2 suggestions here:

1) Try to perform an inplace build-2-build upgrade with the psconfig tool. Open an elevated command prompt on the WFE and execute: `psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force`

2) Increment the version number in the Content Database manually. The WSS_Content database has a table called versions. Select the row with the build version (14.0.4762.1000) and update the value to 14.0.6029.1000

Run the Test-SPContentDatabase cmdlet to verify the change.

Comment: Thanks @JudasIscariot1651 I tried the first suggestion before reaslising what I'd missed out. I re-ran SP config wizard which fixed it, but thanks for your time and suggestions.

Comment: @spartanmouse then you actually did exactly what I suggested, without realising it ;) the Configuration Wizard (`psconfigui`) employs the exact same mechanism as `psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force` invokes